# XNA Sprite - File Not Found

Tags: c#, exception, xna, sprite

I am trying to learn XNA by using Microsoft's tutorials and I am stuck on adding sprites to my content folder. At first I could not find my "Content" directory.

[image: Solution Explorer]

As seen in the above image I managed to add a sprite to IC2013-2Content. Is this right so far? I also managed to give it the name "megaman" which I read creates a .xnb file and adds it to the content folder in the solution directory as seen in the next image.

[image: XNA Project Directory]

I assume that is the correct directory the .xnb file should be in? When I try and run my program I get this error.

[image: Coding error]

Sorry for the overload of images. Does anyone know why I keep getting the File Not Found error?

Thank you.

Comment: *Sorry for the overload of images* is the wrong thing to say. Everyone loves images :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured that because the .xnb file was in a folder called Images I changed the Content.Load to incorporate the sub-directory and it's now working!